# Amazon EMR spam applications by user dr.who?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am working spark processes using python (pyspark). I create an amazon EMR cluster to run my spark scripts, but when cluster is just created a lot of processes ar launched by itself (¿?), when I check cluster UI:

[image: Cluster UI screenshot]

So, when I try to lunch my own script, they enter in an endless queue, sometime ACCEPTED but never get into RUNNING state.

I couldn't find any info about this issue even in amazon forums, so I'll glad any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing your cluster is exposed to the open internet and anyone can submit jobs? Plus, you didn't enable Kerberos, so your cluster is not secure anyway?

Comment: @cricket_007 Hi, this has a security group limited by IP. It is not exposed, also has a key pair to access via ssh.

Comment: Are you able to look at the application masters and see what the jobs are actually trying to do?

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think I can access the code, if I that's what you mean. If I missunderstand, please explain me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Column > Tracking URL > Click ApplicationMaster. Follow more links to the logs to find out what *actions* those applications are taking

Comment: @cricket_007 When I try click 'Tracking Url' it take me to an internal ip (such as `http://ip-192-168-1-32.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1536782226328_0402/`), so I can't access from my browser. Is there a way to review this log from aws amazon panel?

Comment: Not that I know of. I typically do an SSH socks proxy into the AWS network, then all the links work

Comment: Have a look at this also https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/What-is-Dr-who-user-100s-of-yarn-jobs-are-getting-triggered/td-p/68026

Answer (score 1):

you need to check in the security group of the master node, check the inbound traffic,
maybe you have a rule for anywhere, please remove that or try to remove and check if the things work it is a vulnerability.